# fork() pipe() dup2 cant comunicate with external child process

Tags: c, process

Im trying to send something to the child after fork() i've set up dup2 to redirect the out puts for the child. but it looks like it's not getting the stream. 
further more how do i get the out put from the child. 
The file is an external executable that simply prints text but it's not showing. 
Any help please?

Comment: It's a different program entirely,
Basically i want to send stuff to the child, and read it from the child.

Comment: guy forgets the ';' at the end of the statement question gets up voted another asks reasonable question, it goes down...

Comment: @cerkiewny question upvote and downvote does not proves level of question. It is all about `Question shows research effort; It is useful and clear. ` P.S i am not downvoter :)

Comment: I have spent so much time trying to figure it out. Cant get it..Please help!

Comment: did you try reading in the loop? If the read has no data to read it will just return 0 try to surround it with while ((i = read) != 0) to prevent from instant return of 0.

Comment: Also I think you are closing the pipe descriptor to early, if the kernel will notice that the count of the file descriptor is 0 than it will close the pipe and delete its data, you should have 2 children that will read from the pipe or if you want father child communication than you can use the child to read WHILE the parent is writing not in sequence.

Comment: I threw the read(child->childWrite, temp,100); into a while loop and it's just hanging. This has been killing me for the past couple of days.

Comment: Has the external child been set up properly? to me it looks right, but im unsure.

Comment: why did you delete your codes from your post. please put them there so other people may find them useful ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that you called `pipe` twice, you should call it once like:

```
if(pipe(tmpFd) == 0)
{
  //now do fork
}
```

or if you want to create two pipes you should create another variable like `tmpFd2`
so you can do this:

```
if(pipe(tmpFd) == 0 && pipe(tmpFd2) == 0)
{
  /*
   parent can write to tmpFd[1] and child can read from tmpFd[0]
   child can write to tmpFd2[0] and parent can read from tmpFd2[1] 
  */
}
```

now you should pass the both file descriptors(`tmpFd` and `tmpFd2`) as an argument (`argv`) to the socond program.
this way child can communicate with parent.

here is an example of how child and parent will communicate:

```
int main()
{
    char buffer[1024];
    const char child_data[] = "child says hello";
    const char parent_data[] = "parent says hello";

    if(pipe(tmpFd) == 0 && pipe(tmpFd2) == 0)
    {
        if(fork() == (pid_t)0)
        {
            printf("child.\n");
            write(tmpFd[1], child_data, strlen(child_data));
            read(tmpFd2[0], buffer, 100);
            printf("child read: %s\n" , buffer);

        }
        else
        {
            printf("parent.\n");
            write(tmpFd2[1], parent_data, strlen(parent_data));
            read(tmpFd[0], buffer, 100);
            printf("parent read: %s\n" , buffer);           
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("pipe failed.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this example does not use`exec` but it gives you the idea.

Comment: OK, cool, so ive updated that, looks abit better and makes sense. But still problems with the children and parent talking.

Comment: How could i use this as a template to for execv? Thank you so much for helping me out.

Comment: @MarkNicolle pass `tmpFd` and `tmpFd2` as arguments of `exec` function and use them in the second program as command line arguments (`argv`)

Comment: So the best way would be to use execv? also would this work for reading from multiple children, ie other programs? Thanks mate.

Comment: I don't know the answer of the first question but this works for several children, you just pass them the descriptors. Also remember that you can use "Message Queues" and "Unix Sockets" to pass data between to related or unrelated processes. Your welcome dude.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are using `pipe` incorrectly, because it only needs to be called once ([RTM](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html)).
2. You're calling `calloc` incorrectly. Use `calloc (100, sizeof (char))`
3. Don't assign a constant string to a section of dynamically allocated memory. Use `char message[] = "sent from parent"` instead. This way is also beneficial because you can use `sizeof` in `write` instead of `100`. This could also be causing a segmentation fault because the area in memory that `"sent from parent"` is at is not `100` bytes long.
4. Use `execv` instead of `execlp`. There's no need for you to use `execlp`

Comment: How is execv better than execlp?

Comment: @MarkNicolle it's not better. It's just that you aren't even using variable argument lists, so why use `execlp`?

Answer (score 0):

```
there are couple of problem in your code.. Basics of pipe, fork are missing here.
```

I would suggest first clear your pipe and fork knowledge. go threw this example first
for this problem http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~franco/OpSys-304-427/messages/node92.html

```
see below comments from #Comment# tag


void createChildren(void){

struct AgentInfo *child= head; //#Comment1# I am assuming you are getting correct child here

int tmpFd[2];

int parentWrite = tmpFd[OUT]; //#Comment2# you dont need to take this in another variable. Till now its garbage value as you have not passed it threw pipe function. It will initialise inside pipe function


int parentRead = tmpFd[IN];//#Comment3# same as above


while(child !=NULL){
    pipe(tmpFd);
    child->childRead = tmpFd[IN]; 

    pipe(tmpFd); //#Comment4# prev pipe var has been overwriten. you just need one pipe to transfer data from parent to child or vice versa
```

// In Pipe for parent fd tmpFd[1] is for writing fd and tmpFd[0] is for reading
// for child fd tmpFd[0] is for writing and tmpFd[1] is for reading

```
    child->childWrite = tmpFd[OUT];
    child->agentPid = fork();
    char* message = calloc(100,sizeof(char*)); //#Comment5# create this element before fork as it will create twice if you allocate it after fork

    message = "sent from parent\n"; //#Comment6# This is highly misunderstanding of memory allocation if you want to use same memory as you have allocated in calloc than use strcpy function.

//constant string will allocate memory once again




    if(child->agentPid<0){
        exit(-1);

    }
    if(child->agentPid == 0){ //#Comment8# this means its parent code. For child it will be  child->agentPid > 0 write you child code there. after this whoile code is totally wrong

        printf("in the child\n");
        dup2(child->childWrite,STDOUT_FILENO); //#Comment7# Why you are involving STDOUT/IN heare as you just want to transfer data bet parent child. you can use tmpFd for this directly

        dup2(child ->childRead,STDIN_FILENO);
        /*fwrite(message, 100, 1,stdin);*/
        write(STDIN_FILENO, message,100);
        close(child->childRead);
        close(child->childWrite);
        /*close(parentWrite);*/
        /*close(parentRead);*/
        execlp(child->fileName,child->fileName,NULL);
        /*error handled here and exit status*/
    }else{
    /*write(child->childRead,message,100);*/
    /*read(parentRead,message,100);*/
    char* temp = calloc(100,sizeof(char*));
    printf("in parent\n");
    read(child->childWrite, temp,100);
    printf("%s", temp);
    child = child->next;

    }

}
}
```

Comment: Ok so ive fixed up some of those errors, any idea how i could execv the external program so i can get input? thank you

Comment: first of all I should say whenever you call execv your current child source code will be replaced by new source which you are passing.                                                        char* argv[4];
    argv[0] = "ls"; // your exe name
    argv[1] = "-l"; //argument that you want
    argv[2] = "-F";
    argv[3] = NULL;
    execv(argv[0], argv); I hope this will help